# cakePHP timezone and time difference

Tags: php, cakephp, time, cakephp-2.0

In my CakePHP 2 application I have time errors.
**date_default_timezone_set** value inside my **Config/core.php** is **Europe/Athens**. I used it successfully for months.
But my codes gives wrong time values after the Daylight saving time passed in 28 october 2012.

When I put this inside my controller I get right time and date.

```
public function dateTimeShow(){
    echo "date:".date('Y-m-d')."<br>";
    echo "time:".date('H:i:s')."<br>";
}
```

But the **date('H:i:s')** value gives normal time-2:00 values.
How can I debug or solve this?
Thank you

Edit: When I print out `date_default_timezone_get()` I get result: **UTC**
When I print out `ini_get('date.timezone')` I get results: **Europe/Athens** (which is right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error after some weeks. I was importing a vendor's files. And it was corrupting my timezone value. I fixed this after chaning the vendor setting file.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at php.net/setlocale

and use something like this in you Config/bootstrap.php

```
// use nld_nld for windows machine
setlocale(LC_TIME, "nld_nld");
// use nl_NL for linux machine
//setlocale(LC_TIME, "nl_NL");
```

Comment: But my **dateTimeShow** function gives the correct time value. Another controller method gives wrong time..

Comment: please add the code of that other function that gives wrong info